# Visual Studio 2015/Community properties Window keeps disappearing. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to change my build target but the properties window won't open. It flashes white and then goes away. Here is a gif of the issue...

[image: Gif]

[Gfycat link (larger than above gif).](https://gfycat.com/FrigidTintedBumblebee)

So how can I fix this? VS is up-to-date (as far as I know).

What have I tried to fix the issue? I've tried restarting, restarting VS, and a fresh install. On a fresh install VS will let me open the properties menu ONCE but after that point it will no longer let me open it.

Comment: Computer repair 101 - have you tried rebooting?  Kind of a joke, but not really... sometimes restarting VS will solve issues like this, or you may have a crashed instance that could be force closed in Task Manager - a reboot would solve that type of issue.

Comment: @ElementalPete I've tried restarting, restarting VS, and a fresh install. On a fresh install VS will let me open the properties menu ONCE but after that point it will no longer let me open it.

Comment: Hmmm, how about left-clicking the project, clicking "Project" from the main menu at the top of the screen, and then clicking the "Properties" item from that dropdown menu?  Same result?

Comment: Reset your settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx Visual Studio IDE is built with WPF and DirectX, maybe...try to update your graphics card driver? :-S

Comment: @ElementalPete Same result.

Comment: @IgorDamiani Settings reset didn't make a difference. I guess I can try a driver update. Don't think it will do much of anything though.

Comment: After the flash, when you open the "Windows" menu, do you see an entry in the list of windows? Maybe the window is there, but it has size zero, or is shown somewhere outside your desktop.

Comment: @George Not showing up there either :/.

Comment: Do you have any third-party add-ins in Visual studio?

Comment: @George None except for a Unity integration one but that has never caused issues before.

Comment: @George I have a new development that has come up and a weird one at that. When I boot up Visual Studio and don't open it via Unity it will let me modify the properties of the project however after this it will stop letting me do so.

Comment: @Sie so it seems that Unity might have to do something with the issue? Maybe Unity is hooking itself into the Visual Studio IDE when the project properties are opened.

Comment: @George So here what I've tried next after getting fed up with VS 2015... This is strange. So I installed VS 2012, set it as the editor in Unity, opened up my file, and in the solution explorer it is complaining the project is not compatible. However my error is gone that I was having due to a framework problem... Problem solved? I guess.

Comment: @George Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117973/discussion-between-sie-and-george).